# Блок "изменён" поломался

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, вопросы, правки

[Вводится целое число F. Найти число n, для которого значение n-ого числа Фибоначчи является ближайшим числу F, но не больше его. (на си) нужна помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1030500/15479).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На MSE тоже [опубликовал репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334182/260198).

Comment: Нет такой проблемы. Какой браузер?

Comment: @Qwertiy FF. Проблема только в этом вопросе.

Comment: Подтверждаю проблему FF ESR 60.9 на этом вопросе

Comment: У меня так же, но мне казалось, это фича такая)

Comment: @andreymal тоже в FF?

Comment: @Suvitruf да. .

Comment: А вообще у меня в разных вопросах по-разному, вот [ещё один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030563) такой например https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHGvb.png

Comment: Да, в лисе воспроизводится.

Comment: У меня в FF 69.0.1 не воспроизводится. **Upd.:** Воспроизводится, если залогиниться. В разлогиненном режиме всё выглядит нормально.

Comment: Chromium также.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Возможно*, это было связано с тем, что [на тот момент они что-то с разметкой меню делали](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334182/strange-bug-with-edited-block-in-one-question-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment1121083_334182).

Те изменения откатили, сейчас проблема больше не воспроизводится.