# Съезжает разметка у "закрыть"

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, дизайн, правки

Например, у этого вопроса: [Как убрать повторяющейся код "if else" в контролерах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1031012)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Число в скобках переносится на другую строку.

При изменении размеров окна может встать правильно.

Вероятно, связано с этой темой: [Блок “изменён” поломался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9553).

Comment: Думаю, причина та же )

Comment: @Suvitruf, весьма сомнительно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, проблема была та же, что и тут: [Блок "изменён" поломался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9553/15479).

[Адам пишет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334182/strange-bug-with-edited-block-in-one-question-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment1121828_334182), что больше не воспроизводится.