# Порядок автора и редактора

Tags: дефект, дизайн, адаптивный-дизайн

При уменьшении ширины окна блок с отредактировавшим вопрос показывается выше блока с задавшим вопрос. Это неудобно и стоит их поменять местами.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9553/15479

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну там вроде случай, когда должны действия переноситься, а при моей ширине перенос блока явно нужен, но я бы их в другом порядке поставил.